# How to merge meshes but keep coordinates in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

What I am trying to do with threejs is simple. I want to:

- have two cubes with a 1 cube wide gap in between
- and have them be one geometry object with geometry.merge

Note: I'm sorry, I can't find anything on this, and I've been trying for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
var cubes = new THREE.Object3D();
cubes.add(cube1);
cubes.add(cube2);
cubes.add(cube3);
```

This allow you to manipulate them as a single object.

Comment: Will this Reduce lag too?

Comment: appearantly not, this still has a lot of lag in it :l